# Bash script which iterates over files of a path

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have this folder architecture

```
folder
   folder 1 (1)/
       /file1_1.txt
       /file2_2.txt
   folder 2 (2)/
       /file2_1.txt
...
   folder N (N)/
       /fileN_1.txt
       /fileN_2.txt
```

With a script, I would like to iterate over all the folers of the first level (folder1, folder2, folder3) and operate on each .txt file.

What I tried:

```
folder=$1
length=$(expr length "$folder")

for subfolder in $folder/*;
do
    subfoldername=${subfolder:$length+1}
    for h in $subfolder/*;
    do
    echo "h is: "$h
    done
done
```

echo $h display:

```
h is: bdcntest/folder
h is: 1
h is: (1)/*
h is: bdcntest/folder
h is: 2
h is: (2)/*
```

The loop "for h in $subfolder/*;" seams to interpret $subfolder as a string not as a path.
I thought that maybe the spaces in the folders name could be the problem, but I haven't manage to get a solution.

Any idea?

Comment: Use something like that: `for f in folder*/*.txt; do echo "$f"; done`. Do not use `find` for this job. That's overkill. Do not forget to quote the variables when necessary.

Comment: He wants to operate/go into the first lvl of folders - or am I wrong?

Comment: I precise what I mean by "operate": I have also a lot of other kind of file in this differents folders. I would like to copy all the folders of the first level (folder1, folder2, folder3) and each readme.txt and the differents .pdf files presents in this folder. Only this files and not all the other present in each folder (like avi or mp3). And I would like to keep this directory structure of course. The readme.txt and .pdf are always in the first directory, not in a subdirectroy. Also I think it can be difficult to do all this with a find command (?). It's why I was going with bash commands.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello, welcome to Stack overflow!

if I understood your question correctly, do you want something like this?

```
find folder/ -name "*.txt" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

Obviously, one can change the `"cat"` to any other command, this command(or, program) will "operate" on the `*.txt` files in directory `"folder/"` with maxdepth of 1.

`folder` can obviously too, be changed to another folder.

Comment: That's superfluous. Could be done simply by `cat folder/*.txt`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I do not understand what you mean? he wants to go to level one at folder? or am I wrong(Have I misunderstood something? :o  please tell me if any problem is here; sorry - if there is!